# Is it possible to reference the (unknown/variable) height of a parent element when setting the width of a border-radius with CSS?

Tags: css

I'd like to make circular endcaps on the left and right side of a scalable element with CSS. When setting the width/height of the border-radius, 50% is suitable for the height as half of the parent element's height, but I need the width to be the same value. Using a % value for the width is relative to the parent's width, while I need it equal to the height value, or 50% of the parent's height. The parent element can be variable, so I don't have an absolute length to work with.

I thought of using a custom property/variable to store the height of the parent, but I'm not sure how to refer specifically to the length of the height. % is just "relative to parent element", which is ambiguous when it comes to width or height. If I had 50% in a custom property and used that as a variable for a width, it would just get the parent width again I'm assuming.

Comment: I do not think it is possible using CSS (although I might be wrong). But using very simple Javascript this can be done pretty easily. As you can get the properties of another element and use them to set the properties of the current element.

Comment: it seems your are simply looking for something like `border-radius: 999px`.  A big pixel value will do the job

Comment: A large or oversized border radius will result in an oval, rather than a cylindrical pill shape for a rectangle.

Comment: @oosyrag I'm not sure what you mean by an 'oval'. The shape produced with a big pixel value is a 'stadium' (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oval#:~:text=An%20oval%20%28from,of%20an%20ellipse.) and I've just tested with a before pseudo element circle added over the top and it does look exactly like a rectangle with a semi circle at the end(s). Have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry, it did work! I used a big % value instead of a px value, which resulted in the oval.